# Not able to modify object of struct in loop

Tags: c#, collections

I have a List of structure.In the loop i am trying to modify the object's property,which is happening,but when i (Quick look in Visual studio)look into the list object ,the new value is not reflecting.Is it by virtue that the structure's object cannot be modified when in a collection?
I am using generics list with the struct as the type in the list

Comment: Remembering that structs are value types, how are you iterating over the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention "modify the object's property" in the context of a struct, but importantly a struct **is not an object**. Other people have answered as to the issue with structs being copied (and changes discarded), but to take that further the *real* problem here is that you *have* a mutable (changeable) struct *at all*. Unless you are on XNA (or similar) there is simply no need.

If you want to be able to change properties, make it a class:

```
public class Foo {
    public string Bar {get;set;}
}
```

This is now a reference-type, and your changes (`obj.Bar = "abc";`) will be preserved through the foreach. If you really want/need a struct, make it immutable:

```
public struct Foo {
    private readonly string bar;
    public string Bar { get {return bar; }}
    public Foo(string bar) {this.bar = bar;}
}
```

Now you *can't* make the mistake of changing the value of a copy; you would instead have to use the indexer to *swap* the value (`list[i] = new Foo("abc");`). More verbose (and you can't use `foreach`), but correct.

But IMO, use a class. Structs are pretty rare, to be honest. If you aren't sure: class.

Comment: +1 for that Thanks Marc 
more info is on below after i searched about struct on search http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a foreach loop you probably got

[Compiler Error CS1654](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04t3s14w.aspx)

> Error Message Cannot modify members of
>   'variable' because it is a 'read-only
>   variable type'
>
> This error occurs when you try to
>   modify members of a variable which is
>   read-only because it is in a special
>   construct.
>
> **One common area that this occurs is
>   within foreach loops. It is a
>   compile-time error to modify the value
>   of the collection elements. Therefore,
>   you cannot make any modifications to
>   elements that are value types,
>   including structs.**

You could however try

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public int i;
}

List<MyStruct> list = new List<MyStruct> 
        { new MyStruct { i = 1 }, new MyStruct { i = 2 } };

for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    MyStruct val = list[i];
    val.i++;
    list[i] = val;
}
```

**EDIT**

See also [Structs Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(VS.71).aspx)

*Structs vs. Classes*

> Structs may seem similar to classes,
>   but there are important differences
>   that you should be aware of. First of
>   all, classes are reference types and
>   structs are value types.

Comment: Thanks ,I have done the same ,but isnt this creating one more copy of sctruct object in list???

Comment: No, this will be replacing the struct at position i in list with the copied struct, with updated value.

Answer (score 1):

I THINK i know what the problem might be.

```
struct Astruct
{
   int amember;
}

List < Astruct > listofStructs;

foreach(Astruct A in listofStructs)
{
     A.amember = 1337;
}
```

if this is what you are doing...

when you use structs in c# they are not referenced but copied! so that means the contents of your list is being COPIED to A, so when you change A it doesn't change the value in the list!

to solve this problem (if this is your problem...)  either use CLASSES rather than STRUCTS, that way A would be a reference, OR use a manual iterating for loop instead, ie:

```
for(int i=0;i < listofStructs.Count;i++)
{
    listofStructs[i].amember = 1337;
}
```

alternatively, if you’re using a list, you maybe should use an iterator or something... but the above should definitely fix that problem.

Comment: Thumbs down.
Got following compilation error
Error 10 Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Animation.WidgetResolution>.this[int]' because it is not a variable D:\Designer_Tag\Designer\Animation\AnimationPersistance.cs 182 29 Animation

Answer (score 0):

Given the information in your post (although I'd have liked to see the code itself), let me put forth the most probable issue and its fix.

```
   foreach(var s in listOfStructs)
    {
      s.Property = x;
    }
```

s is assigned to a copy of the actual struct in the collection. s.set_Property is now modifying the copy which is thrown away at the end of the current iteration.

This is because 2 value type variables cannot point to the same instance.

```
struct1 = new MyStruct(100, 200);
struct2 = struct1;   // struct2 is now a copy of struct1
```

Now to the problem of how do you modify the instances in a collection:
Get the object to modify in a local variable (copy created). Modify it. Now remove the original object and insert the copy. use `listOfStructs[i] = modifiedInstance`.